# How to add a dropdown timepicker in angular?

Tags: angularjs, popup, angular-ui-bootstrap, timepicker

I'm terribly stuck trying to add a dropdown time picker to an angular app im making.

```
             <div class="col-xs-3">
                //I just want to stick it right in here
            </div>
```

I've tried this http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/905/ and this https://github.com/Geta/angular-timepicker and some other alternatives, I really just need an input field where you can entire a time so I can pass a time (not a date) to my model, but I need it to fit in a small div header i have, so I can't use the standard timepicker element. I'm a complete angular noob so maybe these other methods should be working and I just don't know how to implement them. I tried including the files as scripts and what not but it really isn't working.